# How to load a javascript function properly for a checkmark and button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

HTML/javascript newbie here.

This is my javascript function:

```
function foo() {
    var checker = document.getElementById('signupCheck');
    var sendbtn = document.getElementById('signupBtn');


    checker.onchange = function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            sendbtn.disabled = false;
        } else  {
            sendbtn.disabled = true;
        }
    }

}
```

These are my checkmark and button code:

```
<div style="text-align: center">
<input type="checkbox" id="signupCheck"/>
<a href="main index.php?page=signup"><input type="Submit" id="signupBtn" value="Continue" class="css_button" disabled/></a></div>
```

I am trying to load the javascript function properly because apparently, if you "spam" the button, eventually it lets the user go to the next page. Any suggestions to properly load it?

So far I tried putting window.onload = foo(); in the footer, tried onload= foo() in the body and also after checkmark and button div.

Comment: change your event from onselect to onchange="foo()"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try :

```
<div style="text-align: center">
   <input type="checkbox" id="signupCheck" onchange="foo()" />
<a href="main index.php?page=signup">
    <input type="Submit" id="signupBtn" value="Continue" class="css_button" disabled >
    </a>
</div>
```

and then write your JS:

```
function foo () {

    var checker = document.getElementById('signupCheck');
    var sendbtn = document.getElementById('signupBtn');


    checker.onchange = function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            sendbtn.disabled = false;
        } else  {
            sendbtn.disabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```